# How to pass tuple to a Matlab function from Python

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, matlab-engine

I have a Matlab function that I'm calling from a python script:

```
import matlab.engine

eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
t = (1,2,3)
z = eng.tstFnc(t)
print z
```

The function `tstFnc` is as follows:

```
function [ z ] = tstFnc( a, b, c )
z = a + b + c
```

This does not work, however, as Matlab receives one input instead of three. Could this be made to work?

**Note:** this is a simplified case of what I want to do. In the actual problem I have a variable number of lists that I pass into a Matlab function, which is interpreted in the Matlab function using `varargin`.

Comment: Try `z = eng.tstFnc(*t)` to apply the arguments instead of passing them as a tuple

Comment: @Pyrce I can't believe that worked :D Thanks!

Comment: Great! I'll add it as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As notes in the comments, the arguments need to be applied instead of passed as a tuple of length 1.

`z = eng.tstFnc(*t)`

This causes a call to `tstFnc` with `len(t)` arguments instead of a single tuple argument. Similarly you could just pass each argument individually.

`z = eng.tstFnc(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: I should add that `t = (2,3)` and `z = eng.tstFnc(1, *t)` works too, in case anyone is curious.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate - Yes, that's a standard Pythonic way of splitting up the tuple. BTW, I've already +1ed your question and this answer.

Comment: @rayryeng Yeah, ok, I didn't know :) Thanks!